# recover or access data values in JSON array as string

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, symfony

I have a JSON Response which returns this:

```
[{"name":"value 1"}]
```

In my html.twig I am trying to recover this value like:

```
// note that I recover route parameter in JavaScript var for slug and confChecked
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: Routing.generate('get_product_by_all_config', {slug: $(this).val(selectedSlug), confChecked: $(this).val(checkedConfigString)} ),
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#target').empty();
    $('#target').val(data.name);
    $('#target').append(data.name);
  }
});
```

This my Symfony controller:

```
// I recover $slug and $parameters by Requesr $request
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->getEntityWithParameters($slug, $parameters);

$array = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($entity as $e) {
  $array[$i]['name'] = $e->getName();
  break;
}

$response = new Response();

$data = json_encode($array);

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->setContent($data);

return $response;
```

I have no error, but nothing happened, the value is not display in the `input with id #target`.

Where am I wrong?

### Edit

in my controller I made a `dump($response)`, it returns this:

```
Response {#683 ▼
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#696 ▶}
  #content: "[{"name":"value 1"}]"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

I think the problem is that my jQuery/JavaScript return object for var `selectedSlug` and `checkedConfigString`. Is there a way to make the **var values** as **string** for `php`?

Answer (score 1):

In your example your **JSON** data is an `array` not an object try something like : 
`data[0].name` instead of : `data.name`

Are you sure that your generated route

```
Routing.generate('get_product_by_all_config', {slug: $(this).val(selectedSlug), confChecked: $(this).val(checkedConfigString)} )
```

is well formed ?

`$(this).val(selectedSlug)` and `$(this).val(checkedConfigString)` seems weird to me.

$(this).val(something) sets the value and return an array of object, not the value.

Routes can contains simple type such as Number or String. if you want to send complex data type (object), you must serialize your object and send it in the body of your request (POST only).

You can add a property 'data' in your ajax request containing your object(s) :

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    data : {
        someProp : {property : 'value',...}
    },
    ...
});
```

You can access these datas in your Symfony Action's Controller with

```
$this->get("request")->getContent();
```

In your case it seems that selectedSlug and confChecked are simple types so you may send them as routes params : /myroute/my-slug/1 for example, depending on your routes configuration.

Comment: following your suggestion, I have this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: can you make a console.log(data) in your success callback function (assuming there is no error and the function is called)

Comment: yes of course I already do this. `console.log(data)` return `[]`, `console.log(data[name]` or `console.log(data["name"])` returns me `undefined` and `console.log(data[0].name)` returns me an error `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: I was assuming that the data was correctly transferred. Can you provide a var_dump($response) ?

Comment: see my edit in my initial post. Thank you by the way.

Comment: can you also provide the response to your XHR (given by your browser) ?

Comment: in my browser the response XHR is named `%5Bobject%20Object%5D/%5Bobject%20Object%5D` and retuns me `[]No properties`

Comment: I think you are right in your answer, by setting `$(this).val(selectedSlug)` and `$(this).val(checkedConfigString)`, symfony and attempted to have object and not string. In my form, the variable value are dynamic, how can I proceed to return string and object !